# How to export data to text file in Apache phoenix?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm quite new to HBase and Phoenix.

But is there a way I can **dump/export data to a text file?** It would be highly appreciable if I can specify the field terminator, such as ',', '|>' etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Another Solution. 
After connecting to phoenix with sqlline.py:

1. !outputformat csv
2. !record data.csv
3. select * from system.catalog limit 10;
4. !record
5. !quit

Comment: This seems good except that my output file includes the message "Saving all output to..." and at the end of the select "3 rows selected".  Is there a way to get it *only* output the stuff i want?  or to skip system messages or something?

Comment: I have successfully exported, but some numbers are formatted in scientific notation (1,003E+4) when it should simply be an integer (or long float). How do I export the original number not formated?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid scientific notation?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Apache Pherf](https://phoenix.apache.org/pherf.html).
Pherf arguments:
-export Exports query results to CSV files in CSV_EXPORT directory

Comment: I found this link also. But how can I specify the delimiter, for example '|>', I want? A sample code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try using sed once you have generated the dump?

Comment: Are you sure this exports query output or the performance testing results ?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use sed once you have generated the dump.
In my case, I wanted a `\t` de-limiter. However, the column values were of the form 'A','B','C','D' a simple `s/','/'\t'/g` did the trick for me.